# error in apache starts xampp version 5.6.30

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

Good Morning!

Dear php master how do I fix this error? This happened on a laptop where I have installed x.ampp version 6.5.30, the following mistakes:

> Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
>   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues.
>   If you need more help, copy and post this entire log window on the forums.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should do precisely what it tells you to do: "*Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues. If you need more help, copy and post this entire log window*" (as an edit to your question).

Comment: just taking a wild guess here, but a coupe of years back, when i was still using xampp, I sometimes ran into a problem because skype was using the same port. But to be sure, do as @ObsidianAge said and check the error logs